# How do I fix the "Non-numeric argument to binary operator" error?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, numeric

I am just learning how to use R and received the error reading "non-numeric argument to binary operator." The data I am using on the x-axis is binary and I want to convert the labels on the plot to read pre- and post-devaluation rather than arbitrarily assigning a numeric scale to binary data. What is wrong with my code that is generating this error message?

The problematic two lines of code are:

```
x <- as.factor(Reacquisition$Day) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c("Pre-","Post-devaluation"))
```

Here is the entire code:

```
Reacquisition_gg <- ggplot(Reacquisition,aes(Day, Rate, colour = Group))
Reacquisition_plot <- Reacquisition_gg + 
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "line") + 
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_se, fun.args = list(mult = 1), geom = "errorbar", width = 0.2) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#88A1cc","#1659cc"), labels = c("unpaired", "paired")) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(-5,50)) +
  theme_light() +
  geom_jitter(width = 0.1) +
  x <- as.factor(Reacquisition$Day) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c("Pre-","Post-devaluation"))

print(Reacquisition_plot)
```

And here is the data-set:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This can work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
#Code
Plot <- Reacquisition %>%
  mutate(Day=factor(Day,levels = c(0,1),
                    labels = c("Pre-","Post-devaluation"))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Day, Rate, colour = Group))+
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "line") + 
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_se, fun.args = list(mult = 1),
               geom = "errorbar", width = 0.2) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#88A1cc","#1659cc"),
                     labels = c("unpaired", "paired")) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(-5,50)) +
  theme_light() +
  geom_jitter(width = 0.1)
```

Comment: Thank you! That code worked however I am still not getting the correct labels for "Pre-" and "Post-devaluation" printed on the graph. The labels on the x-axis still print an arbitrary scale from 0-1. Any idea as to why the correct labels aren't showing up on the plot?

Comment: @IsabelleWilson Hi Isabelle, without seeing your data (the screenshot was not useful) I can give you any other reason. Consider inviting me to chat https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187426/how-do-i-chat-with-another-user-on-stackoverflow I am glad to help :)